# Expand one row at a Time in RadGridView - C# Telerik

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, radgridview

I have a rad grid view with hierarchical template. User can expand each row, and in normal mode User can expand several rows. I need to prevent such behavior and let user to only expand one row at a time.

I searched in telerik forums and Google but did not find any helpful code working on winforms radgridview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use radGridView's `ChildViewExpanded event` and a variable to store the last expanded `row index`

```
 int lastExpandedRow = -1;
 private void radGridView_ChildViewExpanded(object sender, ChildViewExpandedEventArgs e)
 {
   int parentRowIndex = e.ParentRow.Index;
   if (lastExpandedRow != -1 && lastExpandedRow != parentRowIndex )
   {
      radGridView.Rows[lastExpandedRow].IsExpanded = false;
   }
   lastExpandedRow = parentRowIndex ;
 }
```

Comment: Where is the question here?

Answer (score 0):

Capture the expanding event, and inside it collapse all the rows, so the newly expanded row will be the only one expanded.

Comment: I tested this, but it will prevent expanding current row also.

Comment: Did you collapse all rows, then expand the row that was clicked?